# update with join sql | error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, update-inner-join

i have to lower the price with 2% for each item where the capacity is more than 200 pcs using two tables where the id's have to be the same and i can not pass this error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

'Catalog' is a table and 'Order' is the second table

```
update Catalog
set price = (price - price*0.02) from Catalog inner join Order on 
(Catalog.idf = Order.idf and Catalog.idp = Order.idp)
where quantity > 200;
```

what could be the bug here? thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what columns are in what tables.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support a `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE`.

Hmmm.  If I speculate that `quantity` is in `order`, then you can use:

```
update Catalog
    set price = 0.98 * price
    where (select o.quantity
           from Orders o 
           where Catalog.idf = Order.idf and Catalog.idp = Order.idp
          ) > 200;
```

I am a bit cautious about this.  This means that there is a 1-1 relationship between `orders` and `catalog`.  If there can be more than one `order` for a catalog entry, then you probably need aggregation.  However, this is the logic you seem to be trying to implement in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `merge` statement as follows:

```
Merge into Catalog c
Using (select * from orders) O
On (c.idf = O.idf and C.idp = O.idp
    And o.quantity > 200)
When matched then
Update set c.price = 0.98 * price;
```